# Dynamic dropdown menus react

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement a dynamic dropdown menu. Clicking on the add button will show a dropdown menu that allow users to select an item, and each dropdown menu has the same list of options. I have the dropdown options store in an array, and clicking the add button will increment another array of options to the array

The issues I am having now is that, clicking the remove button doesn’t reflect what I have removed on the UI. For example, if I remove the first dropdown, it reflects that the second one is deleted.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const disciplines_fake_data = [
  { name: "discipline1", id: 0 },
  { name: "discipline2", id: 1 },
  { name: "discipline3", id: 2 },
  { name: "discipline4", id: 3 },
  { name: "discipline5", id: 4 },
  { name: "discipline6", id: 5 },
  { name: "discipline7", id: 6 },
  { name: "discipline8", id: 7 }
];

export default function Discipline({
  registration,
  handleRemoveDisciplineClick,
  handleSelectDisciplineClick
  // handleInputChange,
}) {
  const [disciplinesDropdowns, setDisciplinesDropdowns] = useState([]);

  const handleAddDisciplineClick = () => {
    setDisciplinesDropdowns((prev) => [...prev, disciplines_fake_data]);
  };

  const handleRemoveDropdownClick = (index) => {
    const newDisciplinesDropdowns = [...disciplinesDropdowns];
    newDisciplinesDropdowns.splice(index, 1);
    setDisciplinesDropdowns([...newDisciplinesDropdowns]);

    handleRemoveDisciplineClick(`otherDisciplines_${index + 1}`);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {disciplinesDropdowns.length > 0 &&
          disciplinesDropdowns.map((disciplines, index) => (
            <div style={{ marginTop: "10px" }} key={index}>
              <article>
                <label htmlFor={`otherDisciplines_${index + 1}`}>
                  Discipline {index + 1}
                </label>
                <button
                  onClick={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    handleRemoveDropdownClick(index);
                  }}
                >
                  REMOVE
                </button>
              </article>
              <select
                defaultValue="choose from all disciplines"
                name={`otherDisciplines_${index + 1}`}
                onChange={handleSelectDisciplineClick}
                // onChange={handleInputChange}
              >
                <option disabled value="choose from all disciplines">
                  -choose from all disciplines-
                </option>
                {disciplines.map((discipline) => (
                  <option key={discipline.id} value={discipline.name}>
                    {discipline.name}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </select>
            </div>
          ))}

        <div style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}>
          <button
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              handleAddDisciplineClick();
            }}
          >
            <span> add another discipline</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


import React, { useState, useReducer, useEffect } from "react";
import _ from "lodash";

import Discipline from "./Discipline";

const initialState = {
  otherDisciplines: []
};

const FORM_ACTION = {
  SELECT_DISCIPLINES: "select more disciplines",
  REMOVE_DISCIPLINES: "remove disciplines"
};

function registrationReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FORM_ACTION.SELECT_DISCIPLINES:
      const name = action.payload.name;
      const value = action.payload.value;
      const newDisciplines = [
        ...state.otherDisciplines,
        {
          [name]: value
        }
      ];

      newDisciplines.map((discipline) => {
        if (discipline[name]) {
          discipline[name] = value;
        }
      });
      return {
        ...state,
        otherDisciplines: _.uniqWith(newDisciplines, _.isEqual)
      };

    case FORM_ACTION.REMOVE_DISCIPLINES:
      return {
        ...state,
        otherDisciplines: state.otherDisciplines.filter(
          (discipline) => Object.keys(discipline)[0] !== action.payload
        )
      };

    default:
      return { ...state, [action.input]: action.value };
  }
}

    export default function App() {
      const [registration, dispatch] = useReducer(
        registrationReducer,
        initialState
      );
    
      console.log(registration);
    
      const handleInputChange = ({ target }) => {
        const { name, value } = target;
    
        const action = {
          input: name,
          value: value
        };
    
        dispatch(action);
      };
    
      return (
        <form
        // onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
        >
          <div>
            <Discipline
              registration={registration}
              handleInputChange={handleInputChange}
              handleSelectDisciplineClick={(e) => {
                const { name, value } = e.target;
                dispatch({
                  type: FORM_ACTION.SELECT_DISCIPLINES,
                  payload: { name, value }
                });
              }}
              handleRemoveDisciplineClick={(discipline) => {
                dispatch({
                  type: FORM_ACTION.REMOVE_DISCIPLINES,
                  payload: discipline
                });
              }}
            />
            );
          </div>
        </form>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using the list index as an identifier for the element is not recommended.
2. Instead of list (disciplinesDropdowns) you can make use of dictionary object to store dropdowns with unique identifiers and pass those unique identifiers to "handleRemoveDropdownClick".
3. Can have a function, that generates random and unique key before adding dropdowns to "disciplinesDropdowns".

Comment: Hi! Thanks the for suggestions! So my disciplinesDropdowns state should be an object of arrays like this { 0: [ ], 1: [ ], … } ?

Comment: Hi,  that works. But you may have to change your logic of saving disciplinesDropdowns, deleting dropdown may not need any changes, since you will be passing unique identifier as an argument.
Hope this helps.